# Convert jQuery find() function to ES6 Alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

My task is to convert jquery to es6 . I am stuck at one point .

Jquery -

```
var $form = $('.class1');
commonfunction($form);

function commonfunction($form) {
  $form.find('.class2')
}
```

ES6 which i am working , i am trying like this .

```
let form = document.querySelector('.class1');
commonfunction(form);

function commonfunction($form) {
  form.find('.class2') 
}
```

I know that find is not supported by raw javascript .How to proceed here ?

Comment: `form.querySelectorAll('.class2')`

Comment: FYI, it is good not too consider everything new "ES6". `querySelector` is newer than the original jQuery releases, but it's been around a lot longer than ES6. Browsers implement many specifications, ES6 is one of them, but is not the specification that defines `querySelector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something  like this

```
form.querySelectorAll('.class2');
```

More detail [here](http://usefulangle.com/post/43/jquery-find-function-in-pure-vanilla-javascript)

Comment: This will grab all of the elements with a class of `.class2` on a page. Including elements outside `form`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox [Not true.](https://jsfiddle.net/vzjgqLkp/) There are potentially confusing aspects to `qSA`, but not when there is only a single selector.

Comment: @lonesomeday [It was true](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll#User_notes). It looks like it's been fixed.

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, the behaviour is exactly the same. You haven't understood it. The element selected by `qSA` will always be a descendent of the subject element. The unexpected behaviour is when you have descendent  selectors, such as `form .class2`. The `form` element would not have to be a descendent of the subject element. [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/vzjgqLkp/1/)